# In js, how can i use my todo list on the other tap?

Tags: javascript

I used javascript, html, and css to create a usable todo list by moving tabs (project todo, personal todo). But it only works on the first tab, not the other tabs. (But it does animate the button being pressed.) I think it's a matter of order, but maybe not. PLEASE HELP ME !! Below is the code in javascript.

```
const todoObjectList1 = [];
const todoObjectList2 = [];

$(".menu1").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $(".menu2").removeClass("on");
})

$(".menu2").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('on');
    $(".menu1").removeClass("on");
})

// project todo

class Todo_Class1 {
    constructor(item){
        this.ulElement1 =item;
    }

    add() {
        const todoInput1 = document.querySelector("#myInput1").value;
        if (todoInput1 == "") {
            alert("You did not enter any item!") 
        } else {
            const todoObject1 = {
                id1 : todoObjectList1.length,
                todoText1 : todoInput1,
                isDone1 : false,
            }

        todoObjectList1.unshift(todoObject1);
        this.display();
        document.querySelector("#myInput1").value = '';

        }
    }

    done_undone(x) {
        const selectedTodoIndex1 = todoObjectList1.findIndex((item)=> item.id1 == x);
        console.log(todoObjectList1[selectedTodoIndex1].isDone1);
        todoObjectList1[selectedTodoIndex1].isDone1 == false ? todoObjectList1[selectedTodoIndex1].isDone1 = true : todoObjectList1[selectedTodoIndex1].isDone1 = false;
        this.display();
    }

    deleteElement(z) {
        const selectedDelIndex1 = todoObjectList1.findIndex((item)=> item.id1 == z);

        todoObjectList1.splice(selectedDelIndex1,1);

        this.display();
    }


    display() {
        this.ulElement1.innerHTML = "";

        todoObjectList1.forEach((object_item1) => {

            const liElement1 = document.createElement("li");
            const delBtn1 = document.createElement("i");

            liElement1.innerText = object_item1.todoText1;
            liElement1.setAttribute("data-id1", object_item1.id1);

            delBtn1.setAttribute("data-id1", object_item1.id1);
            delBtn1.classList.add("far", "fa-trash-alt");

            liElement1.appendChild(delBtn1);
            
            delBtn1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                const deleteId1 = e.target.getAttribute("data-id1");
                myTodoList1.deleteElement(deleteId1);
            })
            
            liElement1.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                const selectedId1 = e.target.getAttribute("data-id1");
                myTodoList1.done_undone(selectedId1);
            })

            if (object_item1.isDone) {
                liElement1.classList.add("checked");
            }

            this.ulElement1.appendChild(liElement1);
        })
    }
} 

// personal todo

class Todo_Class2 {
    constructor(item){
        this.ulElement2 =item;
    }

    add() {
        const todoInput2 = document.querySelector("#myInput2").value;
        if (todoInput2 == "") {
            alert("You did not enter any item!") 
        } else {
            const todoObject2 = {
                id2 : todoObjectList2.length,
                todoText2 : todoInput2,
                isDone2 : false,
            }

        todoObjectList1.unshift(todoObject2);
        this.display();
        document.querySelector("#myInput2").value = '';

        }
    }

    done_undone(x) {
        const selectedTodoIndex2 = todoObjectList2.findIndex((item)=> item.id2 == x);
        console.log(todoObjectList2[selectedTodoIndex2].isDone2);
        todoObjectList2[selectedTodoIndex2].isDone2 == false ? todoObjectList1[selectedTodoIndex2].isDone2 = true : todoObjectList2[selectedTodoIndex2].isDone2 = false;
        this.display();
    }

    deleteElement(z) {
        const selectedDelIndex2 = todoObjectList2.findIndex((item)=> item.id2 == z);

        todoObjectList2.splice(selectedDelIndex2,1);

        this.display();
    }


    display() {
        this.ulElement2.innerHTML = "";

        todoObjectList2.forEach((object_item2) => {

            const liElement2 = document.createElement("li");
            const delBtn2 = document.createElement("i");

            liElement2.innerText = object_item2.todoText2;
            liElement2.setAttribute("data-id2", object_item2.id2);

            delBtn2.setAttribute("data-id2", object_item1.id2);
            delBtn2.classList.add("far", "fa-trash-alt");

            liElement2.appendChild(delBtn2);
            
            delBtn2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                const deleteId2 = e.target.getAttribute("data-id2");
                myTodoList2.deleteElement(deleteId2);
            })
            
            liElement2.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                const selectedId2 = e.target.getAttribute("data-id2");
                myTodoList1.done_undone(selectedId2);
            })

            if (object_item2.isDone) {
                liElement2.classList.add("checked");
            }

            this.ulElement2.appendChild(liElement2);
        })
    }
}

////-----MAIN PROGRAM------------

const listSection1 = document.querySelector("#myUL1");

myTodoList1 = new Todo_Class1(listSection1);

// project todo add

document.querySelector(".addBtn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    myTodoList1.add()
})

document.querySelector("#myInput1").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        myTodoList1.add()
    }
})

// personal todo add

const listSection2 = document.querySelector("#myUL2");

myTodoList2 = new Todo_Class2(listSection2);


document.querySelector(".addBtn2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    myTodoList2.add()
})

document.querySelector("#myInput2").addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        myTodoList2.add()
    }
})
```

Comment: You mean if you open your app in one tab it works, but if you open it a second time in another tab, it doesn't?

Comment: YESS !! But selecting another tap (personal todo) for the first time also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just gave different javascript to different todo taps.
In other javascript, the existing personal part was removed and pasted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).